# VBA excel to Webform

Tags: vba

i did a VBA macro to populate the Webform as below before assigning more code from Excel

But before i can proceed, I am on hit block
this is the code that i use
When i try to click on F5, i cannot manage to input any value on the search button.

what did i do wrong here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahVlY.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images of code - you can copy and paste the text more easily, and it's more useful (no-one has to type out your code in order to help fix it).

Comment: i try to input as text but i received this error --> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getelementsbyclassname` returns a collection of elements which were matched, not a single element, so you need to use `(0)` to indicate you want to work with the first element in that collection (assuming there was at least one match found) Eg:

```
 IE.document.getElementsbyClassName("blah")(0).click
```